# Is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood same as the open interval $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

While reading real analysis, I came across this definition:
**Definition:**(*$\epsilon$-neighbourhood*).Given a real number $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and a positive number $\epsilon > 0$,
the set
$$V_{\epsilon}(a)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\epsilon\}$$
is called the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$.
From this definiton I noticed that $V_{\epsilon}(a)$ consists of all those points whose distance from $a$ is less than $\epsilon$. From this, I concluded that:
$$V_{\epsilon}(a)=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$$
is this alternate definition (or say, theorem) true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Not a theorem, or an alternate definition. This is just what a neighborhood of a point is. An $\epsilon$-neighborhood is just a neighborhood (open ball) around a point with radius $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This isn't a 'theorem', the definition of an open interval is already $(a,b) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | a<x<b\}$, so $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | a-\epsilon < x < a+\epsilon\}$ and $ a-\epsilon < x < a+\epsilon $ is equivalent to saying $|a-x|<\epsilon$

Comment: I think this slight modification is also true:$V_{\epsilon}(a)=[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. Is it true?

Comment: no, since $a - \epsilon \in [a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$, but $|a-\epsilon - a| = \epsilon$, but we defined $V_\epsilon$ to be the set of points whose distance from $a$ is *strictly* less than epsilon.